# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate - Select * from

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

in Spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. how can I a query to perform "Select * from Student" to return a List without providing any parameters using Spring version 3.1.x ?
according to 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html

there is

List
query(String sql, Map paramMap, RowMapper rowMapper)

but i dont want to provide any paramMap because i am doing a "select *".

how can this be done using version 3.1.x ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried simply passing an empty parammap? If I recall correctly the code only uses it if it encounters a param which requires substitution. If your query has none, everything might work fine even with an empty map.

Comment: @Zeus: Please  consider accepting the answer or respond with a comment in case you think its not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Kirill Ch example,  Spring has `BeanPropertyRowMapper`, which can maps a row’s column value to a property by matching their names. Make sure your property and column has the same name. eg orgId with column name ORGID or org_id

```
public List<Organization> getAllOrganization(){
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM organization";
     List<Organization> orgList = namedParamJdbcTemplate.query(sql, new 
     BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Organization.class));

    return orgList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may call `getJdbcOperations()` on your `NamedParameterTemplate`; using the obtained object you may then call e.g. `<T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)`.

Look up the docs, though; as using the above mentioned `query` method does not used a prepared statement. You may use (as the Spring docs mention) `<T> List<T> query(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)` passing `null` as args.

Update:
Just checked Spring's source code and you can just pass an empty paramMap as Gergely suggested.

Update 2:
Any chance to update to a newer Spring version? Spring 3.2.14 e.g. has the method you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
public List<Organization> getAllOrganization(){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM organization";
    List<Organization> orgList = namedParamJdbcTemplate.query(sql, new OrganizationRowMapper());

    return orgList;

}
```

Where is **OrganizationRowMapper**:

[image]